# How to check status of URLs from text file using bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, http, url, ubuntu

I have to check the status of 200 http URLs and find out which of these are broken links. The links are present in a simple text file (say URL.txt present in my ~ folder). I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am a Linux newbie. But I understand the bash shell is very powerful and could help me achieve what I want.

My exact requirement would be to read the text file which has the list of URLs and automatically check if the links are working and write the response to a new file with the URLs and their corresponding status (working/broken).

Comment: How do you check if the url is working? By pinging it ? Could you specify in details the method you wish to use ? Otherwise, the reading file part is quite easy in bash

Comment: @Ploutox - I was trying to look for invalid urls - one which returned 404 errors. Figured it out using curl.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I created a file "checkurls.sh" and placed it in my home directory where the urls.txt file is also located. I gave execute privileges to the file using

`$chmod +x checkurls.sh`

The contents of checkurls.sh is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url
do
    urlstatus=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$url" )
    echo "$url  $urlstatus" >> urlstatus.txt
done < $1
```

Finally, I executed it from command line using the following -

`$./checkurls.sh urls.txt`

Voila! It works.

Comment: Awesome! If you're testing for redirects, you can also print the destination URL and bust most 301 issues by using `curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}  %{redirect_url}'`

Comment: Nice solution and nice tip with including redirect. I added some parallelism in adapted solution. It was too long to fit in comment.

Comment: @brablc - Please post your own answer with the parallelism.

Comment: @Enigmativity it is already here - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40125113/793937 .

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -ru 4 LINE; do
    read -r REP < <(exec curl -IsS "$LINE" 2>&1)
    echo "$LINE: $REP"
done 4< "$1"
```

Usage:

```
bash script.sh urls-list.txt
```

Sample:

```
http://not-exist.com/abc.html
https://kernel.org/nothing.html
http://kernel.org/index.html
https://kernel.org/index.html
```

Output:

```
http://not-exist.com/abc.html: curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'not-exist.com'
https://kernel.org/nothing.html: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
http://kernel.org/index.html: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
https://kernel.org/index.html: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

For everything, read the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/). See `man curl`, `help`, `man bash` as well.

Answer (score 6):

What about to add some parallelism to the accepted solution. Lets modify the script `chkurl.sh` to be little easier to read and to handle just one request at a time:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=${1?Pass URL as parameter!}
curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "$URL %{http_code} %{redirect_url}\n" "$URL"
```

And now you check your list using:

```
cat URL.txt | xargs -P 4 -L1 ./chkurl.sh
```

This could finish the job up to 4 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

Herewith my full script that checks URLs listed in a file passed as an argument e.g. 'checkurls.sh listofurls.txt'.

What it does:

- check url using curl and return HTTP status code
- send email notifications when url returns other code than 200
- create a temporary lock file for failed urls (file naming could be improved)
- send email notification when url becoms available again
- remove lock file once url becomes available to avoid further notifications
- log events to a file and handle increasing log file size (AKA log
  rotation, uncomment echo if code 200 logging required)

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

EMAIL=" your@email.com"
DATENOW=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`
LOG_FILE="checkurls.log"
c=0

while read url
do
  ((c++))
  LOCK_FILE="checkurls$c.lock"
  urlstatus=$(/usr/bin/curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$url" )

  if [ "$urlstatus" = "200" ]
   then
    #echo "$DATENOW OK $urlstatus connection->$url" >> $LOG_FILE
    [ -e $LOCK_FILE ] && /bin/rm -f -- $LOCK_FILE > /dev/null && /bin/mail -s "NOTIFICATION URL OK: $url" $EMAIL <<< 'The URL is back online'
else
    echo "$DATENOW FAIL $urlstatus connection->$url" >> $LOG_FILE
    if [ -e $LOCK_FILE ]
     then
        #no action - awaiting URL to be fixed
        :
    else
        /bin/mail -s "NOTIFICATION URL DOWN: $url" $EMAIL <<< 'Failed to reach or URL problem'
        /bin/touch $LOCK_FILE
    fi
  fi
done < $1

# REMOVE LOG FILE IF LARGER THAN 100MB
# alow up to 2000 lines average
maxsize=120000
size=$(/usr/bin/du -k "$LOG_FILE" | /bin/cut -f 1)
if [ $size -ge $maxsize ]; then
     /bin/rm -f -- $LOG_FILE > /dev/null
     echo "$DATENOW LOG file [$LOG_FILE] has been recreated" > $LOG_FILE
else
     #do nothing
     :
fi
```

Please note that changing order of listed urls in text file will affect any existing lock files (remove all .lock files to avoid confusion). It would be improved by using url as file name but certain characters such as : @ / ? & would have to be handled for operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I recently released [deadlink](https://github.com/nschloe/deadlink), a command-line tool for finding broken links in files. Install with

```
pip install deadlink
```

and use as

```
deadlink check /path/to/file/or/directory
```

or

```
deadlink replace-redirects /path/to/file/or/directory
```

The latter will replace permanent redirects (301) in the specified files.

Example output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your input file contains one url per line you can use a script to read each line, then try to ping the url, if ping success then the url is valid

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT="Urls.txt"
OUTPUT="result.txt"
while read line ;
do
  if ping -c 1 $line &> /dev/null
  then
      echo "$line valid" >> $OUTPUT
  else
      echo "$line not valid " >> $OUTPUT
  fi
done < $INPUT
exit
```

ping options :

```
-c count
      Stop after sending count ECHO_REQUEST packets. With deadline option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the timeout expires.
```

you can use this option as well to limit waiting time

```
 -W timeout
      Time to wait for a response, in seconds. The option affects only timeout in absense
      of any responses, otherwise ping waits for two RTTs.
```

Comment: You can try ping, but some firewalls may block ICMP packets.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -s -I --http2 http://$1 >> fullscan_curl.txt | cut -d:  -f1 fullscan_curl.txt | cat fullscan_curl.txt | grep HTTP >> fullscan_httpstatus.txt
```

its work me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).