# Bash shell script to find Robots meta tag value

Tags: linux, bash, http, redirect, x-robots-tag

I've found this bash script to [check status of URLs from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135347/how-to-check-status-of-urls-from-text-file-using-bash-shell-script/25136588) and print the destination URL when having redirections :

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url
do
    dt=$(date '+%H:%M:%S');
    urlstatus=$(curl -kH 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{redirect_url}' "$url" )
    echo "$url $urlstatus $dt" >> urlstatus.txt

done < $1
```

I'm not that good in bash : I'd like to add - for each url - the value of its Robots meta tag (if is exists)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a Bash specific topic, but you can use curl and probably a little bit awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'd really suggest a DOM parser (e.g. Nokogiri, hxselect, etc.),
but you can do this for instance (Handles lines starting with `<meta` and "extracts" the value of the robots' attribute content):

```
curl -s "$url" | sed -n '/\<meta/s/\<meta[[:space:]][[:space:]]*name="*robots"*[[:space:]][[:space:]]*content="*\([^"]*\)"*\>/\1/p'
```

This will print the value of the attribute or the empty string if not available.

Do you need a pure Bash solution? Or do you have `sed`?

Comment: Thanks, I've just added a new instruction before echo :
``metarobotsheader=$(curl -s "$url" | sed -n '/\<meta/s/\<meta[[:space:]][[:space:]]*name="*robots"*[[:space:]][[:space:]]*content="*\([^"]*\)"*\>/\1/p')``

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line to extract the *meta* header for robots from the source code of the page and modify the line with *echo* to show its value:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url
do
    dt=$(date '+%H:%M:%S');
    urlstatus=$(curl -kH 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{redirect_url}' "$url" )
    metarobotsheader=$(curl -kH 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --silent "$url" | grep -P -i "<meta.+robots" )
    echo "$url $urlstatus $dt $metarobotsheader" >> urlstatus.txt
done < $1
```

This example records the original line with the *meta* header for robots.

If you want to put a mark "-" when the page has no *meta* header for robots, you can change the `metarobotsheader` line, and put this one:

```
    metarobotsheader=$(curl -kH 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --silent "$url" | grep -P -i "<meta.+robots" || echo "-")
```

If you want to extract the exact value of the attribute, you can change that line:

```
    metarobotsheader="$(curl -kH 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --silent "$url" | grep -P -i "<meta.+robots" | perl -e '$line = <STDIN>; if ( $line =~ m#content=[\x27"]?(\w+)[\x27"]?#i) { print "$1"; } else {print "no_meta_robots";}')"
```

When the URL doesn't contain any *meta* header for robots, it will show *no_meta_robots*.